# Vibration in android API 21

Tags: android, android-vibration

I want to vibrate the device when I get a error response from my server.I have tried all kinds of things to make it vibrate but it isn't working.This is my code if required,

```
Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.shake);
        edittext.startAnimation(shake);
        edittext.setHintTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F62217"));
        edittext.setHint(string_id);
        Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator) context
                .getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibe.vibrate(500);
```

Also added the user-permission in my app,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

Any suggestions?..have I missed anything?..any help is appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you verified that, you are getting the response from server as expected ?

Comment: check your import if correct:
`import android.os.Vibrator;` and try adding `this` before `context` like `Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator)  this.context
                .getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);`

Comment: @DavidJhons yes David..I have verified it..its just an error response..a string..it wouldn't affect the core android concepts.

Comment: @hrskrs yes I have checked..the same code works till kitkat.It vibrates the device as it should.But it isn't able to do the same thing on Lollipop device.

Comment: I hope this link will be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32709260/android-detect-if-the-vibrate-setting-in-the-device-is-on-or-off-esp-for-the-c/45240695#45240695